# App Configuration affecting VS Web Server Hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration, asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-2022

In my ASP.NET API im having an issue for a while where i cannot host my web app locally using VS web server on ports other than the default ones (i.e. http: 5000, https: 5001). VS keeps on waiting for web server to listen on the ports specified in my LaunchProfile.json indefinitely while the app is being hosted on the default ports.

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "HHT_API": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7291;http://localhost:7290"
    }
  }
}
```

What does this have to do with ConfigurationBuilder?

Well, I was having an argument with my colleague regarding how Configuration should be provided in DI. He relies on DI to auto-provide the configuration, while I do it explicitly
through creating an IConfiguration object from ConfigurationBuilder

```
IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
    .Build();

builder.Services.AddSingleton(configuration);
```

after deciding to try it his way, i realized that the issue is gone, i can now host the app using any set of ports unlike before.

What am i missing here?

EDIT 1: to clarify, below is program.cs for both cases:


**Case 1**: Creating an IConfiguration object with Configuration builder and passing it as a DI service (app is hosted on default ports only)

```
using HHT_API.Databases.HHTCustom;
using HHT_API.Modules.HHT.Models.ResponseModels;
using HHT_API.Modules.Logger.Models;
using HHT_API.Modules.Middleware.API;
using HHT_API.WrapperManagement;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
    })
    .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
    {
        //configure a special response for invalid model state
        options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>{
            ModelStateDictionary modelStatePtr = context.ModelState;  
            modelStatePtr.Remove(modelStatePtr.ElementAt(0).Key); //remove the key of the class model itself
            
            List<string> invalidFields = modelStatePtr.Keys.Select(x => x.Replace("$", "").Replace(".", "")).ToList();
            
            var result = new OkObjectResult(new MainResponseModel<object>() {
                MessageCode = (int)StatusCode.ModelValidationError,
                MessageText = $"Invalid entry for ({string.Join(", ", invalidFields)}). Please check your input and try again!",
                Data = null
            });
            return result;
        };
    });

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddHsts(options =>
{
    options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(31536000);
    options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
    options.Preload = true;
});
builder.Services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
{
    options.HttpsPort = 443;
    options.RedirectStatusCode = 308;
});

builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options =>{
    options.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = false;
});

// [1]: creating an IConfiguration object with Configuration builder and passing it as a DI service

IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
    .Build();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(configuration);

byte[] bConnectionString = Convert.FromBase64String(configuration["HHTCustom"]);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<HHTCustomContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bConnectionString));
    //options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<ComponentsWrapperManager>();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

var app = builder.Build();

/// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

// configure swagger behavior for each envirnonment
if (app.Environment.IsProduction() || app.Environment.IsStaging()) {
    app.UseHsts();
    //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseSwagger();
    string sVirtualPath = builder.Configuration.GetSection("VirtualPath").Value;
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint(sVirtualPath + "/swagger/v1/swagger.json","HHT v1"));

}
else {     //development
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions {
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor |
    ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

//use custom middleware for logging requests and responses
app.UseMiddleware<APIMiddleware>();

app.Run();
```

**Case 2**: Configuration is provided as a default application configuration source by ASP.NET (Works fine with the desired unique ports specified in LaunchProfile.json)

```
using HHT_API.Databases.HHTCustom;
using HHT_API.Modules.HHT.Models.ResponseModels;
using HHT_API.Modules.Logger.Models;
using HHT_API.Modules.Middleware.API;
using HHT_API.WrapperManagement;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
    })
    .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
    {
        //configure a special response for invalid model state
        options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>{
            ModelStateDictionary modelStatePtr = context.ModelState;  
            modelStatePtr.Remove(modelStatePtr.ElementAt(0).Key); //remove the key of the class model itself
            
            List<string> invalidFields = modelStatePtr.Keys.Select(x => x.Replace("$", "").Replace(".", "")).ToList();
            
            var result = new OkObjectResult(new MainResponseModel<object>() {
                MessageCode = (int)StatusCode.ModelValidationError,
                MessageText = $"Invalid entry for ({string.Join(", ", invalidFields)}). Please check your input and try again!",
                Data = null
            });
            return result;
        };
    });

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddHsts(options =>
{
    options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(31536000);
    options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
    options.Preload = true;
});
builder.Services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
{
    options.HttpsPort = 443;
    options.RedirectStatusCode = 308;
});

builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options =>{
    options.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = false;
});

// [2] configuration is provided as a default application configuration source by ASP.NET
byte[] bConnectionString = Convert.FromBase64String(builder.Configuration["HHTCustom"]);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<HHTCustomContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bConnectionString));
    //options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<ComponentsWrapperManager>();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

var app = builder.Build();

/// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

// configure swagger behavior for each envirnonment
if (app.Environment.IsProduction() || app.Environment.IsStaging()) {
    app.UseHsts();
    //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseSwagger();
    string sVirtualPath = builder.Configuration.GetSection("VirtualPath").Value;
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint(sVirtualPath + "/swagger/v1/swagger.json","HHT v1"));

}
else {     //development
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions {
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor |
    ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

//use custom middleware for logging requests and responses
app.UseMiddleware<APIMiddleware>();

app.Run();
```

Comment: could you please share the problematic Program.cs and the good-working Program.cs? By the way, could you please help check whether [this section about Application and Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#application-and-host-configuration) answered your question?

Comment: @TinyWang, Thanks for your comment. the article above proves that there is no need to provide an IConfiguration object as a service in DI since appsettings is already a default App Configuration source. problem here is how is it related to VS Web Server app hosting. clarifications have been provided

Comment: Thank a lot for your coming back,  according to your code snippets, we can see that the only difference between the 2 Program.cs is that you added the `IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()` to inject appsettings.json, per my humble opinion it won't influence the launchsettting. In your problem, it's the reason making your web hosting to always listen the default port but not the ports set in launchsettings.json.  I deduce that it is due to the configuration overrides some other settings, but I didn't find any documents to explain it, so I don't know the reason.. Sorry.